# Why does “filename.m” gets deleted when I use “dynare” command in Octave?

Tags: octave

I wrote a model to solve using dynare in octave. After writing the model, I save it with “.m” format. Then I type “dynare filename” in octave’s command window to run the model but instead the file gets deleted.

Oddly, it doesn’t happen if I use the command on a file with “.mod” format.

I’m using Octave 5.2.0 since the dynare only works with this version.

Please help me if you can. Tnx a lot.

Comment: Can you give an example that I can try on my computer?

Comment: I downloaded dynare and can confirm this. This seems like a bug (a rather serious one at that!) with dynare itself. I would advise you to report this as a bug to them (https://git.dynare.org/Dynare/dynare/-/issues) and get help straight from the source.

Comment: In general, this seems like a very specific project, and alas, I'm sorry to say that the installation of dynare from source was very buggy and problematic (though obviously one has some sympathy ... for an academic offering it looks like a very big project). The ubuntu precompiled binaries were not without problems either (e.g. lots of assumptions about default paths that would not necessarily hold true for many users). In general with non-commercial projects like these you are probably generally better off asking directly at the developer's site for help with such bugs rather than on SO ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used Dynare 4.5 instead of the recent stable release 4.6. As documented in the manual, the only supported file-types in Dynare are `.mod` and `.dyn`. You cannot name your file `.m` as Dynare will preprocess your `.mod`-file and create an m-file with the same name. Usually, you would get an explicit error message. However, in Octave, the following code is executed first:

```
% Workaround for a strange bug with Octave: if there is any call to exist(fname)
% before the call to the preprocessor, then Octave will use the old copy of
% the .m instead of the newly generated one. Deleting the .m beforehand
% fixes the problem.
if isoctave && length(dir([fname(1:(end-4)) '.m'])) > 0
    delete([fname(1:(end-4)) '.m'])
end
```

Dynare 4.6 instead moved to Matlab-classes. There you will get an explicit error message.